# JMS (Java Messaging Service) client in flutter?

Tags: flutter, jms

I'm developing an app using Flutter, which is a great cross platform tool, but I wonder if anyone has experience about consuming JMS services in Flutter? I didn't manage to find any related documentation so far.
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Flutter other than quickly reviewing some of the documentation, but as a developer on the Apache ActiveMQ (message broker) project I can say that in order to support clients which run in mobile and browser environments brokers will typically implement STOMP. Flutter apps are written in [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language)) and a quick search on the [Dart package website](https://pub.dev/) reveals [a number of STOMP clients](https://pub.dev/packages?q=stomp). I recommend you go with one of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin!
Good advice, I was pretty stuck there, and it would have taken me ages to find the STOMP option.
I will definitely follow that lead :)
Best regards

Comment: And sorry I forgot to mark your answer as good. I do believe it is, and if one has to consume JMS directly from dart, it's probably the less painful way to go. In practice, I ended up setting up my own backend which consumed the JMS services in Java, and published a REST API via Spring which I then could use from my Flutter/dart app.